# How to display SQLAlchemy "one-to-many" child object in jinja?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

### Summary

I need some help displaying the HTML text from a SQLAlchemy "one-to-many" child element. I've succeeded in committing the changes to the database, but I'm not too sure how to display the text on the screen.

Below is `app.py` where I call all my functions for the Flask app

### Question

How can I display the child `scrapingAccount()` elements "name" and "username" that corresponds with the targeted bot from the `botList()` model? All the files are down below.

#### app.py

```
# Parent element
class botList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'botlist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    channel = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bots = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    igUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    igPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    scrapingAccounts = db.relationship("scrapingAccount", backref="botlist")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Username %r>' % self.id


# Child element
class scrapingAccount(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'scrapingaccount'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("botlist.id"))


# On specific bot page
@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def updateBot(id):
    bot_to_update = botList.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("updateBotButton"):
            bot_to_update.username = request.form['username']
            bot_to_update.channel = request.form['channel']
            bot_to_update.bots = request.form['bots']
            bot_to_update.status = request.form['status']
            bot_to_update.igUsername = request.form['igUsername']
            bot_to_update.igPassword = request.form['igPassword']
            bot_to_update.ytUsername = request.form['ytUsername']
            bot_to_update.ytPassword = request.form['ytPassword']
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('/')
            except:
                return "There was a problem updating that bot."

        elif request.form.get("updateAccountButton"):
            if request.method == "POST":
                name = request.form['igname']
                username = request.form['iguser']
                new_account = scrapingAccount(name=name, username=username)
                try:
                    db.session.add(new_account)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect('#')
                except:
                    return "There was a problem adding an account."
            else:
                return redirect('/update/<int:id>')

    else:       # Below is where I need help
        accounts = scrapingAccount.query.order_by(scrapingAccount.id)
        return render_template("update.html", bot_to_update=bot_to_update, bot=bot_to_update, accounts=accounts)
```

#### update.html

```
{% block content %}

{% for account in accounts %}
{% for bot in account.scrapingaccount %}
<form action="/update/{{bot.id}}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="igname" id="igname" placeholder="eg. Jane Doe" value="{{bot.igname}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="iguser" id="iguser" placeholder="eg. jandoe" value="{{bot.iguser}}"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" name="updateBotButton" value="Update accounts">
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the attributes "username" and "name" of the objects of
the type "ScrapingAccount" which belong to a specific object of the type "BotList",
I recommend the following procedure.

```
def update_bot(id):
    bot_to_update = BotList.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
    else: 
        return render_template('update.html', bot=bot_to_update)
```

The "backref" parameter specified within your relationship maps the object of
the "BotList" class specified by the ForeignKey in the respective object of the
"ScrapingAccount" class.
The same applies to the definition of the relationship itself. The referenced
accounts are assigned to the respective object of the "BotList" type using the
key as a list and can be queried as such.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for account in bot.scraping_accounts -%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ account.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ account.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor -%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mattwelter I'm just interested in python and flask and like to help others. It was pure coincidence that I have now answered several of your questions in a row. If you have any further questions, leave a comment or we might run into each other again. Have fun!

Comment: I opened another question you might be able to help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374866/how-to-fix-sqlalchemy-form-db-session-commit-to-the-wrong-parent-object