# How to fix SQLAlchemy form "db.session.commit()" to the wrong parent object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

My SQLAlchemy form commits `db.session.commit()` to the `.first()` parent?

I have a "one-to-many" situation where I can add new a child to a specific parent object, but for some reason when I commit changes to the child, it automatically commits to the `.first()` parent. Not sure how I got into this situation, I assume it's just a mistype somewhere in my code. I'd like to commit changes to

**How can I commit `db.session.commit()` to the correct parent?**

#### app.py

```
# Parent
class botList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'botlist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    channel = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bots = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    igUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    igPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    scrapingAccounts = db.relationship("scrapingAccount", backref="owner", lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Username %r>' % self.id

# Child
class scrapingAccount(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'scrapingaccount'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("botlist.id"))


@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def updateBot(id):
    bot_to_update = botList.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("updateBotButton"):
            bot_to_update.username = request.form['username']
            bot_to_update.channel = request.form['channel']
            bot_to_update.bots = request.form['bots']
            bot_to_update.status = request.form['status']
            bot_to_update.igUsername = request.form['igUsername']
            bot_to_update.igPassword = request.form['igPassword']
            bot_to_update.ytUsername = request.form['ytUsername']
            bot_to_update.ytPassword = request.form['ytPassword']
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('#')
            except:
                return "There was a problem updating that bot."

        elif request.form.get("addAccountButton"):
            if request.method == "POST":
                name = request.form['addigname']
                username = request.form['addiguser']
                new_account = scrapingAccount(name=name, username=username)
                try:
                    db.session.add(new_account)
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect('#')
                except:
                    return "There was a problem adding an account."
            else:
                return redirect('#')

        elif request.form.get("updateAccountButton"):
            if request.method == "POST":
                account = scrapingAccount.query.filter_by(owner_id=bot_to_update.id, id=request.form['accountid']).first_or_404()
                account.name = request.form['igname']
                account.username = request.form['iguser']
                try:
                    db.session.commit()
                    return redirect('#')
                except:
                    return "There was a problem updating an account."
            else:
                return redirect('#')
    else:
        return render_template("update.html", bot=bot_to_update)
```

#### update.html

```
{% for account in bot.scrapingAccounts %}
<form action="/update/{{bot.id}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="accountid" value="{{ account.id }}"/>
    <input type="text" name="igname" id="igname" placeholder="eg. Jane Doe" value="{{account.name}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="iguser" id="iguser" placeholder="eg. jandoe" value="{{account.username}}"/>
    <input type="submit" name="updateAccountButton" value="Update">
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the previous speaker (@PGHE).
It's not the session.
Your query for the "scrapingAccounts" is the reason.
The query is based on the id passed in the URL. However, this belongs to the BotList.

```
<form action="/update/{{bot.id}}" method="POST">
```

However, you ask for an account here.

```
accounts = scrapingAccount.query.get_or_404(id)
```

The most sensible thing would be if you would not write everything in the same route but would distribute tasks to several. This not only improves the structure of your application, but also makes it clearer.
The [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)
paradigm could serve as a guide for a better structure. Using [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/) can make
this even easier.

---

The following approach is a hacky, quick fix.

```
# Parent
class botList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'botlist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    channel = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bots = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    igUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    igPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytUsername = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    ytPassword = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
    scrapingAccounts = db.relationship("scrapingAccount", 
        backref="owner", 
        lazy='dynamic', 
        # Make sure that the referenced child objects are deleted when the 
        # parent object is deleted.
        cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Username %r>' % self.id

# Child
class scrapingAccount(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'scrapingaccount'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    # To avoid unassigned accounts, you can forbid empty entries for the foreign key.
    # An error will be thrown if you try to set it to null / none.
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("botlist.id"), nullable=False)


@app.route('/update/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def updateBot(id):
    bot_to_update = botList.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # If it is a POST request.
        if request.form.get("updateBotButton"):
            bot_to_update.username = request.form['username']
            bot_to_update.channel = request.form['channel']
            bot_to_update.bots = request.form['bots']
            bot_to_update.status = request.form['status']
            bot_to_update.igUsername = request.form['igUsername']
            bot_to_update.igPassword = request.form['igPassword']
            bot_to_update.ytUsername = request.form['ytUsername']
            bot_to_update.ytPassword = request.form['ytPassword']
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('#')
            except:
                return "There was a problem updating that bot."

        elif request.form.get("addAccountButton"):
            name = request.form['addigname']
            username = request.form['addiguser']
            # You want to add an account to the bot here, so you have to set the
            # reference, otherwise it will be saved, but it does not belong anywhere.
            new_account = scrapingAccount(
                name=name,
                username=username,
                owner_id=bot_to_update.id
            )
            db.session.add(new_account)
            # Instead of assigning the associated bot id to the new account and
            # adding it to the session, you can also add it to the scrapingAccounts
            # list. Then you don't need to add it to the session as the parent is 
            # already part of it. The owner_id is assigned automatically.
            #
            # bot_to_update.scrapingAccounts.add(new_account)
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('#')
            except:
                return "There was a problem adding an account."

        elif request.form.get("updateAccountButton"):
            # Request the account using its id and owner_id.
            account = scrapingAccount.query.filter_by(
                owner_id=bot_to_update.id,
                id=request.form['accountid']
            ).first_or_404()
            account.name = request.form['igname']
            account.username = request.form['iguser']
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect('#')
            except:
                return "There was a problem updating an account."
    else:
        return render_template("update.html", bot=bot_to_update)
```

```
{% for account in bot.scrapingAccounts %}
<form action="/update/{{bot.id}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="accountid" value="{{ account.id }}"/>
    <input type="text" name="igname" id="igname" placeholder="eg. Jane Doe" value="{{account.name}}"/>
    <input type="text" name="iguser" id="iguser" placeholder="eg. jandoe" value="{{account.username}}"/>
    <input type="submit" name="updateAccountButton" value="Update accounts">
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Another alternative could be to use optional parameters within the route / URL.

Comment: Your hacky quick fix fixed it! Thank you thank you

Comment: @mattwelter Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: The think adding the `account = scrapingAccount.query.filter_by(owner_id=bot_to_update.id, id=request.form['accountid']).first_or_404()` somehow made the program unable to `db.session.add(new_account)` (the elif above the one you fixed) so I've updated the initial post with everything available to look at if you wanna give it a shot.

Comment: @mattwelter I have updated my answer and have tried to clarify the changes through comments. The newly created accounts were not assigned to the bots because the foreign key was not set. They were saved without a reference.

Comment: You're the man @Detlef do you have a Twitter?

Comment: @mattwelter Nope. Why? Is it for your bot project?

Comment: Nope you just seem like a chill guy

Comment: ah okay, I posted another question if you wanna give it a try, has to do with SQLAlchemy databases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66392319/how-to-connect-sqlalchemy-database-object-id-to-specific-directory

Comment: @mattwelter Saw your new question. What do you mean by that? I do not understand the question.

Comment: I have a list of "bots" I would like to execute from the Flask app (you've been helping me develop). So lets say if I clicked a button that corresponds with `botList.id == 3`, I would like to execute the program associated with Bot 3. This would hopefully replace the process of going to terminal, doing `cd /path/to/dir` and `python /path/to/file/main.py` Does that make sense?

Comment: @mattwelter Yeah. Sounds like import or subprocess. I have to think about it for a while.

Comment: @mattwelter Sorry, no idea. It seems to me that you are working towards a task that could be achieved with [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/). But I have no experience with it. It's too hard for me at the moment.

Comment: @mattwelter My [example of a buggy app launcher](https://github.com/origin-unknown/botanik) may help you. It's kept very simple and the approach is not the safest. I think you will understand the code and how it works, and can adapt it to your needs. Unfortunately, the output of the started applications cannot be received. This makes troubleshooting a little more difficult.

Comment: @mattwelter An asynchronous implementation would be possible via [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html). This would certainly be nicer, the implementation is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Been looking into the differences between asynchronous and multiprocessing pools in Python, what's your Discord? Maybe it'll be easier to communicate there

Answer (score 0):

You're querying your table `scrapingaccount` by its `id` column, and returning a potentially unrelated account to your bot list. You want to query `scrapingaccount` by the `owner_id` column.

This line:

```
accounts = scrapingAccount.query.get_or_404(id)
```

should be:

```
accounts = db.session.query(scrapingAccount).filter(scrapingAccount.owner_id == id).all()
```

Edit: I have assumed `id` in your function is the `id` for the BotList table.

Comment: I received `accounts.name = request.form['igname'] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'` as an error. I would assume `accounts.name` is the wrong method to call the name of the specific account? How can I fix this?

Comment: The function call `.all()` returns a list of results. You said you have a one-to-many relationship in your question. You would have to iterate through the list and set the `name` attribute. If you only expect one row to be returned you can call `.first()` instead.